# Is it possible to `style.apply()` function which will change few style properties?

Tags: pandas

Please consider the next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    return ['color: black' if v > 0 else '' for v in x]

def bar(x):
    return ['background-color: darkorange' if v > 0 else '' for v in x]


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['A1','B1', 'A2', 'B2'])
colnames = [c for c in df.columns if 'A' in c]

df.style.apply(foo, subset=colnames).apply(bar, subset=colnames)
```

[image]

Is there a way to pass `'color: black'` and `'background-color: darkorange'` in a single function?

**PS:** I know that there is such thing as [`Styler.set_properties()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html), but you can't use it with condition.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    return ['color: yellow; background-color: darkorange; text-decoration: underline' if v > 0 else '' for v in x]

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['A1','B1', 'A2', 'B2'])
colnames = [c for c in df.columns if 'A' in c]

df.style.apply(foo, subset=colnames)
```

Separate styles with ';':

[image]

Comment: I tried comma before I post this question on StackOverflow. Semicolon works great and I am just happy about it :)